# How do I delete a remote branch that is named orgin/branchname

Tags: git, github, gitlab

Naively, I thought that  `git push origin origin/branchname`, which was suggested by tab completion, would do the same as `git push origin branchname`. However, it created a new remote branch named "origin/branchname". I want to delete this branch while keeping the remote branch named "branchname" on orign.

I tried `git push -d origin origin/branchname` and `git push -d origin remotes/origin/branchname`. But both do not exist. Note that I can not use `git push -d origin branchname` since this would delete the remote branch named branchname and not the remote branch named "origin/branchname".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the delete parameter after `origin`.

This will delete the branch named `origin/branchname` but leave `branchname` intact.

```
git push origin --delete origin/branchname
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! Interesting that the --delte flag works while the shorter -d, which I always thought to be an abbreviation of --delete, does not.